# Daily sending quota exceeded for email via java

Tags: java, smtp, gmail

I have a java application sending email via my gmail account. Suddenly today I find this exception. I guess my gmail block is it? So what is the solution to this problem?

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.4.5 Daily sending quota exceeded. y4sm4213404obj.10
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.data(SMTPTransport.java:1849)
Transport Problem
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1099)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at commServer$MailProcessor.run(commServer.java:2263)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Limit the number of emails you send on a daily basis?!

Answer (score 16):

GMail accounts can and often will be temporarily suspended from usage if it appears that you are a probable spammer or spreading viruses by email or otherwise bringing harm to others and thus violating GMail's policy.

here are he quick rule book for your refrence

From: [Bulk mailing using Gmail](http://www.labnol.org/internet/email/gmail-daily-limit-sending-bulk-email/2191/) by Amit Agarwal at Digital Inspiration

> **Rule 1.**
>
> If you access Gmail via POP or IMAP clients (like Microsoft Outlook),
>   you can send an email message to a maximum of 100 people at a time.
>   Cross the limit and your account will be disabled for a day with the
>   error "550 5.4.5 Daily sending quota exceeded."
>
> **Rule 2.**
>
> If you access Gmail from the browser, you may not address an email
>   message to more than 500 people at a time. Try adding any more
>   recipients in the To, CC or BCC field and your Gmail account will get
>   probably disabled for 24-72 hours. Error: "Gmail Lockdown in Secton 4"
>
> **Rule 3.**
>
> Always double check email addresses of recipients before hitting the
>   Send button in Gmail. That's because your account will get disabled if
>   the email message contains a large number of non-existent or broken
>   addresses (<25 ?) that bounce back on failed delivery.
>
> **Rule 4:**
>
> This is slightly unrelated but still important - Google will disable
>   your Gmail account permanently if you don't check your Gmail email for
>   a period of nine months. All the stored messages will be deleted and
>   you Gmail address (user name) may be released for others to grab it.

In End gmail is for personal use only and if you are using it for nay kind of testing or other things suggest you to get an mail server account

here is what google says about [sending limits](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22839&topic=1669057&ctx=topic)

Comment: +1, very nice explanation. However, if you're copying someone else's page verbatim, you might want to mention it...

Comment: Oh..i got what you have said..I mentioned his name thanks for the pointing for correction :)

Comment: I would put the link to the content _before_ you copy it into your answer.  Give the link and then quote it with indenting.

Comment: hi i think is better to setup our own SMTP server right? Is it very difficult to setup on linux environment. Beside domain name what else is needed?

Comment: if you are working in some organization, than they already have all these setup all you need to get in touch with your system admin ask for details and you are happy to go, else will prefer to get any ready to use solution. for your own you need a mail server software which can do work for you one such mail server coming to my mind is `James - Apache`

Comment: which is more reliable sendmail or james-apache? any comments?

Comment: personal i have not worked with any of them but if asked will go `james` but that my choice.Can ask separate question for inputs

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to pay for it, there are some SMTP relay solutions out there that you can use, such as [AuthSMTP](http://www.authsmtp.com/).

Once you sign up to AuthSMTP, you'd just change the mail properties and pay based on the number of e-mails you want to send a month. I used it for a while because gmail smtp was (seemingly at random) blocking e-mails coming out of Amazon's ec2 cloud.

I have no affiliation with AuthSMTP. It's pretty cheap for low levels of e-mail, but can get pricey if you are sending a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I used the Thunderbird Mail Merge extension to send an email to around 500 people. Unfortunately this hit the Google Apps limit and all further emails were blocked.

Worse still - the limit seems to still be in place today (the day after) which is highly disruptive and I couldn't get any work done.

The solution for me just to use an alternative SMTP server to send emails which can be easily configured in Thunderbird by adding it to the Outgoing Server (SMTP) section and then selecting it in the email account you're trying to use.

I have a cPanel webserver with the SMTP set up for this account which I can use, but any SMTP server should do the job temporarily. You may be able to find one by searching for free SMTP server. Alternatively you could set up one on your local computer as described here:
[local smtp server to send mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570471/local-smtp-server-to-send-mail)