# Where is the sendmail.ini

Tags: php, xampp

I've been trying to create a newsletter for users to key in their email so I can send them a note using xampp. But all the videos I've watched there is a sendmail.ini file inside their xampp to change. But my whole xampp folder does not have a sendmail.ini file. Why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

Comment: hi yes thanks I've managed to change the C:\xampp\php\php.ini but I can't find the c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini in my xampp folder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34000669/sendmail-folder-does-not-exist-in-xampp-directory