# PHP and XAMPP : sendmail folder does not exist

Tags: php, email, xampp, sendmail

I'm currently reading the book "Head First: PHP and MySQL". In one of the chapters, they demonstrated how to send an email with the PHP function

```
mail()
```

I couldn't send an email with it. I searched it up on Google and found out that I need a folder called "sendmail" in my XAMPP directory and I do not have it.

Is there another way to send an email using PHP that does not require the Sendmail folder? Or even a way to fix this disappearance of the Sendmail folder? Thank you in advance.

Note: I'm a beginner in PHP

I tried editing the php.ini file in my PHP folder inside my XAMPP directory. However, most blogs and articles that I've read instructed me to find a folder called Sendmail, which I do not have. Having the Sendmail folder would allow me to edit the contents of the sendmail.ini file. But since I do not have it, I can not change anything, therefore I can't send an email with the traditional mail() function from PHP.

Comment: sendmail folder always presents there if not please re-install xampp.

Comment: Check out this answer, seems like that might be your issue aswell:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49627544/13319578

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xamp email not working on offline, you need to be online server. before someday it's working offline, but you should go online with any apache server it's working mail function

Comment: Yes, I eventually deployed my project in a real hosting web server, and the mail works there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send mail on your local server with xampp, you have to install a tool to receive the mails. I use https://toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/users-manual.html.