# SMTP error. Data not accepted.SMTP server error

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

In my web server, I am using phpmailer with google mail server, but after sending less than 70 emails I am getting the following mailer and SMTP error:

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385942/daily-sending-quota-exceeded-for-email-via-java

Comment: Evidently your limit is below what you're trying to send.